# How to assign objects in Array string value names in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have created a class for stocks, and created a few objects with type of this class. I then created an array with these objects stored inside with the end goal of iterating through the array to output the values of each of these stocks. Now, I am having trouble displaying the name of the objects of this array when iterating through each one.

```
    NSArray *stocks = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    stocks = @[apple, lvs, verizon];

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < stocks.count; i++) {
        BNRStockHolding *s = stocks[i];
        NSLog(@"The value of %@ is %.2f", s, [s valueInDollars]);
    }
```

The output here is the following:

2014-11-10 16:30:45.246 Stocks Challenge[3777:303] The value of  is 3000.00

2014-11-10 16:30:45.248 Stocks Challenge[3777:303] The value of  is 5000.00

2014-11-10 16:30:45.249 Stocks Challenge[3777:303] The value of  is 8750.00

I suspect this is the case because it is displaying the actual memory address for which the pointer is addressed to. How can I display the actual name given to the object?

Comment: You mean "the name of variables you gave"?

Comment: yes, the "object variable" names I gave, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to print object s, the override  description method in BNRStockHolding

Comment: maybe thats the issue? That I have not declared / defined a description method for the class I created?

Comment: I'm assuming you want me to create a description method for that class using: - (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<#format string#>", <#arguments#>];
}